# Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How can I solve this, I can do this in Activities, but I can't do this in Fragment.

> Will it causes any issues and why?

> Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in fragment

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```

**Full code here:**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentProfileBinding binding;

private TextView name;
private CircleImageView profile;
FirebaseDatabase database;
FirebaseStorage storage;


public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View rootView = binding.getRoot();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

    binding.nameId1.setText(name);
    Glide.with(ProfileFragment.this).load(profile)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
            .into(binding.profile);



    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in fragment

Because [getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()) method is apart of the [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) class and **not** of a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html), hence the error. So in order to access the getIntent() method, you need to call the activity first. So the following line might do the trick:

```
String name = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Alternatively, you can use a Bundle as explained in one of the answers from the following post:

- [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: When I'm using it, it doesn't show any data..
**String name = getActivity (). GetIntent (). GetStringExtra ("name");**

Comment: How do you check that? Besides that, how do you add the data to Intent? Please edit your question and add the code that does that.

Comment: I'm showing the name and picture in the chat activity from the firebase database and the exact same data I want to see in the fragment which will be the profile fragment.

Comment: Ok, what is the exact code that you are using now and doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Right, how can I fix this...

Comment: My last comment is a question. Can you answer it?

Comment: Yes, I read your last comment, that's right.

Comment: You read the comment but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: **I have used this code once in chat activity and it is working properly, I want to use it again in fragment to display the profile picture and name.**

Comment: To properly use it in the Fragment, you need to call getActivity(). If you have added the method call, then be sure you have added the correct data. *I want to use it again in fragment to display the profile picture and name.* This is what the code from my answer does.